# Why the subtle cross-browser differences in Event Object

Tags: javascript, dom, events, cross-browser, dom-events

The following declaration at the window level:

```
    var event; // for IE
    var event = "anything"; // for Chrome
```

will destroy the event object as used here:

```
    <div onMouseOver = "alert(event.type);">Mouseover Div</div>
```

Firefox does not seem phased by either declaration.

I realize that declaring a variable with the name "event" is bad code but I am curious about the technical difference here, e.g. that the use of var in IE reinitializes the variable to null, whereas Chrome will not overwrite with a var declaration unless a value is explicitly assigned, and maybe FF holds the event object outside of the window's var declaration scope altogether.

This is more of a curiosity. I ran into a bug in IE on a site outside of my control that was caused by this and the more I looked into the more I saw subtle differences between browsers. Just wondering if anyone had any insights here.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? It all boils to down to just different browser vendors have different and inconsistent DOM APIs and rendering engines.

Comment: Tim Down's reply answers my question - thanks!

Comment: If his answer answered your question, you should mark it as the correct answer so he gets the points and credit

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Still getting the lay of the land here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In IE, `event` is a property of the `window` object and is used in event handlers functions to access the event being handled. In other browsers such as Firefox, the situation is that in an event handler attribute, the JavaScript code inside the attribute is called as though it forms the body of a function into which has been passed a parameter called `event` that corresponds to the event being handled. So in

```
<div onmouseover="alert(event.type);">Mouseover Div</div>
```

the mouseover code is effectively

```
function(event) {
    alert(event.type);
}
```

and the `event` parameter overrides any `event` declared in a containing scope, whereas in IE, it's

```
function() {
    alert(event.type);
}
```

and the `event` identifier is resolved as a property of the global object (i.e. `window`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Tim - that makes perfect sense. So does Chrome handle the event object similar to IE? It seems to fail on: var event = null;. But this doesn't seem to be the case across WebKit as Safari seems to handle it fine.

Comment: I'm not sure yet, hence my vagueness in the phrase "other browsers such as Firefox". It would seem likely from what you say that Chrome's mechanism is similar to IE's, but I'll do some research.

Comment: It seems almost certain that Chrome is working the same way as IE: in an event handler attribute, `window.event === event` returns `true` and setting a global variable called `event` breaks things, since the global object is the last thing JavaScript checks when trying to resolve an identifier. The situation in Safari 4 is curious: `window.event === event` returns `true` but defining an `event` global variable does not override the value of `event` inside the event handler, so I'd conclude that Safari is both setting `window.event` and passing in the same object as the `event` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I appreciate you explaining your method here.

Answer (score 5):

The "event" object in IE is a property of the "window" object; that is, it's global. In Firefox, it's a value constructed and passed in to event handlers.

If you use jQuery or some other framework, usually the event handling support will normalize the "event" object into something that works identically across browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the added information about frameworks normalizing the event object. Good insight.

Comment: If you like the answers you got, you should vote them up. That's how StackOverflow works for everybody!

Comment: Thanks Pointy, I am new here and haven't gotten the required 15 points yet. But I will be sure to when I do.

Comment: Pointy :so , in IE the event is global so all `foo's`  like `onclick='foo()'` functions will know the event via `window.event` , whereas FF is sending the `event` to the wrapper function so i'll have to use `onclick='foo(event)'` so eventually i'll have `function (event){foo(event);}` ( same as chrome)....am I right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Well, the traditional "hack" is to declare "event" as a parameter to the handler function, and then write `event = event || window.event;` as the first statement of the function.