# Event keyword in js

Tags: javascript, events

I found this code working in Chrome, FF, and IE. However, I can't find any references to the "magic" `event` keyword on the web. See [this](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm)

```js
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handler(e){
                alert(e);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 onclick="handler(event);alert(0)">Click on this text</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

This script STOPS working if I change `event` in brackets to something else. Is that a deprecated keyword?

Answer (score 25):

The [`Event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) is automatically passed to all event handlers. If you add event handlers with `addEventListener`, you can choose the parameter name (like you did in `handler`). But for code attached with the `onclick` attribute, you can only access the event object via the implicit variable `event`.

If you want to know more about event handling in general, I suggest to read about it at [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html).

Also have a look at [MDC - Event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Event_Handlers):

> These are properties that correspond to the HTML 'on' event attributes.
>
> Unlike the corresponding attributes, the values of these properties are functions (or any other object implementing the EventListener interface) rather than a string. In fact, assigning an event attribute in HTML creates a wrapper function around the specified code. For example, given the following HTML:
>
> ```
> <div onclick="foo();">click me!</div>
> ```
>
> If `element` is a reference to this `div`, the value of `element.onclick` is effectively:
>
> ```
> function onclick(event) {
>    foo();
> }
> ```
>
> Note how the event object is passed as parameter `event` to this wrapper function.

Comment: Hi Felix. What if I write `<div onclick="foo(event);">click me!</div>` so its still create a wrapper function  with an `event` param ? (twice ??)

Comment: @Royi: Yes, the function will be like `function(event) { foo(event); }` (example: http://jsfiddle.net/dmNZe/). The content of the HTML attribute is the body of the function.

Comment: So why Do I get undefined here ? it suppose to know the event from its parent http://jsbin.com/erejoh/9/edit (FF)

Comment: In your function you should have `console.log(evt)`. `CheckDigit` does not have access to the scope of the function it was called in. It cannot access `event`.

Comment: That's because you defined `f2` *inside* `f1` hence it's a closure. But in your example, you did not define `CheckDigit` inside the event handler, you are just calling it from there. The event handler situation is more like  http://jsbin.com/exicay/1/edit.

Comment: "She" say, that are the answer of my question, but i have questions to this answer, but this answer is over 10 years old ... My question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74743158/problems-with-event

Comment: This is true for Chromium, but not Mozilla browsers (`event` keyword not reserved - see my answer)

Comment: @DominicCerisano: I'm talking about event handlers attached via the `onclick` *attribute*, since that's what the question is about, not via the `onclick` property. This works in all browsers: `<div onclick="console.log(event)">`. Your answer demonstrates that Firefox doesn't make the current event object available as *global variable*, but I never claimed that it does.

Answer (score 5):

When an event attribute is set, an implicit Function is created  with `event` as the first argument.  When the event fires, the event object is passed to that function.  There wasn't a solid definition on this behavior until HTML 5 (which is still a draft), but it's been this way for a long time in the major browsers and that's how it made it into the spec:

> When an event handler's Function object is invoked, its `call()` callback must be invoked with one argument, set to the `Event` object of the event in question.

That argument is aptly named `event` for obvious reasons.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#events

Comment: +1. I was writing a similar answer. One clarification: in some browsers (IE), `event` resolves to `window.event` rather than being the parameter supplied to the implicit Function object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196299/why-the-subtle-cross-browser-differences-in-event-object/2196356#2196356

Answer (score 3):

This really threw me. The following 'typo' works in Chromium, but not FF:

```
some_worker.onmessage = function(e) {

    // do stuff

    if (e.data instanceof ArrayBuffer)
        intArray = new Uint8Array(event.data);

    // do other stuff
};
```

Chromium was observing the implicit keyword for 'event' but FF threw an 'undefined variable' error! Just changed 'event' to 'e' and all is well.

I notice that even stackoverflow's code markup observes 'event' as an implicit keyword ... not to knock FF, since it detected the typo.

Answer (score 0):

The word `event` is not only an "other reserved word" in JavaScript, it is a always reserved word in all JavaScript Events (`Event`). See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

For an Event with a `function` like `onclick="myFunction()"`, there are two solutions.

**First**: The `onclick="myFunction(event)"` passed the `event` to the `function`. This is similar by `this`.

You can test it with `onclick="consloe.log(event)"` and `onclick="consloe.log(this)"`. `event` is here a reserved word equally `this`. `this` contains the (HTML) Element. `event` contains the Event.

Consider `onclick="myFunction(evt)"` don't work (Error: `evt` is undefined).

Whit the example below, the `event` passed not only into the `myFunction()`, but it can used as a variable inside the function. This is not necessary in simple matters like this, because `event` is always global inside the `function`.

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" onclick="myFunction(event)" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">example.com</a>
<script>
function myFunction(evt) {
  var confirmresult = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (confirmresult == true) {
    // OK = go away!
  } else {
    // Cancel = stay here!
    evt.preventDefault(); // is in this case the same as event.preventDefault();
  }
};
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usfrc6dn/

**Second**: Nothing is vissible passed in the `onclick="myFunction()"`. The `event` is used inside the `function`.

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" onclick="myFunction()" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">example.com</a>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var confirmresult = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (confirmresult == true) {
    // OK = go away!
  } else {
    // Cancel = stay here!
    event.preventDefault();
  }
};
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qczt587u/

Only the second methode is **valide** in the reference of the docs, because about the using of `event` as `onclick="myFunction(event)"` is nothing to find, respectively only for `onclick="myFunction(this)"`. When you have other information, please make a correction.

When you use `onclick="myFunction(event)"`, you can use the `event` inside the function as a variable like `function myFunction(evt) { evt.preventDefault();}`. But that have a little bit risk. Either, the `event` is automatically passed to `functions` that are embeeded or called inside the `function`. Also is only `onclick="myFunction()"` without risk and also valid.

Examples:

```
<div id="foo" onclick="foo();">click me!</div>
function foo(evt) {
  console.log(evt); // undefined
  console.log(event); // the Event "click" Object
}
```

```
<div id="foo" onclick="foo(evt);">click me!</div>
// ERROR: the variable "evt" is not defined!
```

```
<div id="foo" onclick="foo(event);">click me!</div>
function foo(evt) {
  console.log(evt); // the Event "click" Object
  console.log(event); // the Event "click" Object
}
```

```
<div id="foo" onclick="foo();">click me!</div>
function foo() {
  console.log(this); // the Function "foo" Object
  console.log(event); // the Event "click" Object
}
```

```
<div id="foo" onclick="foo(this);">click me!</div>
function foo() {
  console.log(this); // the Function "foo" Object
  console.log(event); // the Event "click" Object
}
```

```
<div id="foo" onclick="foo(this);">click me!</div>
function foo(element) {
  console.log(element); // the Element "div" Object
  console.log(this); // the Function "foo" Object
  console.log(event); // the Event "click" Object
}
```

```
<div id="foo" onclick="foo(this);">click me!</div>
function foo(this) {
  // ERROR: foo is not a function.
  // Cause: 'this' is a reserved word.
  console.log(element);
  console.log(this);
  console.log(event);
}
```

```
<div id="foo" onclick="foo(this);">click me!</div>
function foo(event) {
  console.log(this); // the Function "foo" Object
  console.log(event); // the Event "click" Object
}
```

There are also differences between `this` and `event` that are to consider.

**Conclusion**: Only `onclick="myFunction()"` is without risk and also valid in the matter of `event`.

Comment: *"because about the using of event as onclick="myFunction(event)" is nothing to find"*  Here it is: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#getting-the-current-value-of-the-event-handler . Step 3.9 says that the created function has a parameter `event`.

Comment: `event` is not a reserved word: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ReservedWord

Comment: I had tested more with that. `event` is always present in all functions, that called with an event like `onclick` and also in all functions there are called in such a function, deeper and deeper, always present without passing it. But, it is possible to overwrite `event` and use it as a conventional variable in such a function. This is a potential danger, and this is promoted when pass the `event` as a `e` or similar. Passing is not necessary. The question is: why use a `e`, when `event` is always present? A `e` is only necessary by short code.

Comment: *"[...] always present without passing it"* Because in addition to the `event` **parameter**, which only the event handler has, there is also a *global* `event` variable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Answer (score -3):

I guess your are trying to pass the clicked HTML element to your `handler()` function. The correct way to do that i your code is: 
`<h1 onclick="handler(this);">Click on this text</h1>`

However I strongly recommend avoid this approach. Avoid having styling and behavior defined on the HTML. Please read the following article:
[Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: With inline event registering, `event` actually refers to `window.event`, which returns an Event object of the event fired, while `this` references an HTMLElement object of that element in question.