# Javascript is not working in firefox and IE but works in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome

I am developing an HTML page with many textfields like userid and username, I have added a javascript code like this in separate .js file

```
function CommonKeyPressIsAlpha(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123)){
        document.getElementById("errordisp").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errordisp").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid name!";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Whenever user types in username text field, I am calling this function to validate that user types only characters. I am calling this function in username text fields:

```
onkeypress="return CommonKeyPressIsAlpha(evt);"
```

It works fine in chrome but not in firefox and in IE, Whats the problem?

Comment: Please be aware of the differences between Java and JavaScript! They are _not_ the same!

Comment: Make sure you run your Javascript through [JSLINT](http://www.jslint.com/) and [validate your markup](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `event` into the handler in your `onkeypress` attribute:

```
onkeypress="return CommonKeyPressIsAlpha(event);"
```

This works in all major browsers but relies on using `event` rather than `evt` in the attribute. I've written about the details of how this works on SO [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196299/why-the-subtle-cross-browser-differences-in-event-object/2196356#2196356).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is relying on a Chrome bug where the anonymous function compiled for an inline event handler (`onkeypress` in your case) has its one argument named `evt` in Chrome.  The spec calls for that argument to be named `event`.  See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=80912

The solution is to use `onkeypress="return CommonKeyPressIsAlpha(event);"`