# How to judge IE event type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

I learnt some js code from several books,
like:

```
function doSomething(e) {
    if (!e) {
        var e = window.event;
        alert("this is IE!");
    } 
}
```

suppose I have a element:

```
<h1 onclick="doSomething(event)">Hello World2</h1>
```

when I click it, it doesn't alert in IE (at least in IE6). Is the way I use not correct?

The second question is, assume it could work, every time I use it:

I have to send a event parameter even if I don't do it?
Can I judge IE event type without the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

That's because with what you have, `e` is always a reference to an `Event` object. `event` in the `onclick` attribute resolves to `window.event` in IE, while in browsers such as Firefox that do not support `window.event` there is an `event` variable available within the scope of the attribute value. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2196356/96100).

The situation where you do need to check for `window.event` is when you assign the event handler using a property:

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
h1.onclick = doSomething;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you meant was this

```
function doSomething(e) {
  if (window.event) {
    e = window.event;
    alert("this is IE!");
  }
  // here you can use e in either IE or Gecko/webkit
}
```

Comment: I don't think this fixes anything. The issue is that in the code in the question, `e` always exists in all browsers.

Comment: In my opinion what I posted works and will alert, what was posted originally will also work but do nothing.

Comment: You're right that it solves the immediate problem of getting the alert to show in IE.

Answer (score -1):

Youo haven't written any else coniditon thats why its doing nothing,

As per your code When you click on the link Hello world an event passes and you wrote like this (!E) which is false ,so it doesn't do anything

Try this it will alert

```
function doSomething(e) {
    if (e) {
        var e = window.event;
        alert("this is IE!");
    } 
}
```

If you want to use window event you can do like **window.event.target** for firefox and for ie **window.event.srcElement**