# Why does is x and y immutable in JavaScript running in an <IMG> event handler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, scope, immutability

I'm Using Chrome in case this is a browser-specific behaviour

When I try to set the value of the `x` variable using JavaScript in an image's `onLoad` or `onError` event handler I'm not able to. `x` and `y` seem to be set to the coordinates of the image and when I try to change them the value is not updated and no errors are logged in the JS console.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/brth8zxy/

Code in that page:

```
<img src="https://media1.tenor.com/m/557GUrcXp14AAAAC/jinx-cat-javascript.gif" onLoad="alert(`x=${x}...\nNow setting x=100`);x=100;alert(`x=${x}\nWell that didn't work... Why?`)">
```

Interestingly this behaviour isn't present if I call a function in the `onLoad` event handler. Maybe something to do with scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior that you're mentioning is indeed related to the scope. Let me share my insights on this in the context of your example.

So, when you use `x` directly in the `onLoad` attribute, it refers to the `x` property of the global `window` object. In the context of an event handler, the global `window` object is not the same as the scope in which the event handler is executed<sup>1</sup>. Event handlers run in the context of the element that triggered the event<sup>2</sup>.

Now, in your example the `onLoad` event handler is executed in the context of the `<img>` element. Since the `<img>` element does not have an `x` property, the event handler looks up the prototype chain and finds the `x` property on the `window` object. This is why the value of `x` does not change when you try to set it to 100.

So, what will happen if you use a function in the `onLoad` event handler, as you have mentioned?

```html
  <!-- The answer is you create a new scope for the x variable, 
which allows you to set and update its value as expected.-->

<script>
  function handleImageLoad() {
    let x = 0;
    alert(`x=${x}...\nNow setting x=100`);
    x = 100;
    alert(`x=${x}\nNow it works!`);
  }
</script>

<img src="https://media1.tenor.com/m/557GUrcXp14AAAAC/jinx-cat-javascript.gif" onLoad="handleImageLoad()">
```

---

##### References:

1. [Last paragraph on How scope works](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/#how-it-works)
2. [Event and Dom Nodes](https://eloquentjavascript.net/15_event.html#p_tVKEGdxeqi)
3. [Why the subtle cross browser differences in event object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196299/why-the-subtle-cross-browser-differences-in-event-object)

Comment: Oneliner ```<img src="https://media1.tenor.com/m/557GUrcXp14AAAAC/jinx-cat-javascript.gif" onLoad="(()=>{let x;alert(`x=${x}...\nNow setting x=100`);x=100;alert(`x=${x}\nWell that didn't work... Why?`)})()">```. Always remember to declare your variables

Comment: Yup thanks @Konrad. We can definitely do it like this too. I mentioned it in a separate script tag just to provide clarity to OP.

Comment: Thank you. Great references too make this a nice, high quality answer!